# How to decrypt encrypted data stored in BSTR

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, wincrypt

I have seen the other links on this site about this topic but they are not helpful. If anyone can help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

I am reading a line of encrypted text generated with the WinCrypt API using Visual Studio C++ 2010 express like this:

```
BSTR element;
HRESULT txt = command_body->get_innerText(&element);
size_t len = SysStringLen(element);
unsigned char * cmds;
cmds = (char *)malloc(len);
int ret = wcstombs(cmds,element,len);
```

The debugger shows that `element` is pointing to:

```
"ƒ¦Þ’Î 80:—ÇE³Ž(ùÖðRñ¨5·®•D²Q „× O»C¤ôýdÉùèGñ(åÒ¬¶»“ŽYÞŸÇi‹Bú{l!‹#dŽ "
```

`element` has data type `wchar_t *`, however in order for decryption to take place I need it as a char *. The data was encrypted with RC4 using WinCrypt.
I have tried `wcstombs` and it does not work at all. Results in `cmds` being `"[][]"`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I need to somehow have this data as a `char *` or perhaps I am missing something completely. From what I have read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx) on MSDN it would appear that I would need to specify a new locale..but I am not sure which locale to specify in order for this data to make sense...

Here is the full code:

```
int main()
{
OleInitialize(NULL);            
IWebBrowser2* m_pInetExplorer;  
HRESULT hr;
CLSID clsid;
LPUNKNOWN punk=NULL;
CLSIDFromProgID (OLESTR("InternetExplorer.Application"), &clsid);
hr = CoCreateInstance (clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_SERVER, IID_IUnknown, (LPVOID *) &punk);
VARIANT vars[4];
memset(vars,0,sizeof(vars));
BSTR BStrURL = ::SysAllocString(L"http://127.0.0.1:8000/testing.html");
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    punk->QueryInterface (IID_IWebBrowser2, (LPVOID *) &m_pInetExplorer);
    punk->Release();
    m_pInetExplorer->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);
    HRESULT hrie = m_pInetExplorer->Navigate(BStrURL,vars,vars+1,vars+2,vars+3);    //Go to webpage
    if (SUCCEEDED(hrie))
    {
        VARIANT_BOOL bBusy = VARIANT_TRUE;
        while(bBusy == VARIANT_TRUE)
        {
                Sleep(500);
                m_pInetExplorer->get_Busy(&bBusy);
        }
        IDispatch* pDisp;
        HRESULT test_doc = m_pInetExplorer->get_Document(&pDisp);
        if(SUCCEEDED(test_doc))
        {
            IHTMLDocument2* pHTMLDocument2;
            HRESULT hr;
            hr = pDisp->QueryInterface( IID_IHTMLDocument2,(void**)&pHTMLDocument2 );
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IHTMLElement* command_body;
                HRESULT get_body = pHTMLDocument2->get_body(&command_body);
                if(SUCCEEDED(get_body))
                {
                    BSTR element;
                    HRESULT txt = command_body->get_innerText(&element);
                    size_t len = SysStringLen(element);
                    unsigned char * cmds;
                    cmds = (char *)malloc(len);
                    memcpy(cmds,element,len);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: `wchar_t * element="anything";` wouldn't compile; show your actual code. `SysStringLen` only works on a `BSTR` properly allocated with `SysStringAlloc`, which `element` apparently isn't. The result of encryption is binary data - how on earth did you manage to get it as a Unicode string?

Comment: [`SysStringLen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) expects a `BSTR` as its argument, which is a string type used in COM. It has the string length in the first 2 or 4 bytes, with the actual characters following. Use [`wcslen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcslen) to find the length of your string. And are you sure about the need to convert to a `char *` string? Seems a bit odd for Windows API functions to insist on that.

Comment: [How to convert wchar_t* to char*?](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/87362/how-to-convert-wchar_t-to-char)

Comment: @Praetorian turns out his "I tried this" wasn't actually the real code

Comment: I recommend you modify the server to encode the binary data with Base64 or Hex encoding. Just dumping binary data into a text format like HTML and hoping it will come out intact on the other end - you are gonna have a bad time.

Comment: @Bubo the first thing you must do is look at the encrypted data on the server end and make sure that the data you have received into your client is exactly the same . As Igor suggests , it seems likely that some of it was lost in translation.

Comment: Can you clarify whether the `"ƒ¦Þ’Î` means individual wide characters `ƒ`, `¦`, `Þ`, etc.; or is this binary data that's been packed into a BSTR?

Comment: "The data was encrypted with RC4" Where in your code you are doing RC4 decryption? Your `wcstombs` is apparently not something supposed to decrypt (by design).

Comment: If the BSTR really contains binary data instead or a meaningful string (I know some programs dump binary data in a BSTR because it's easier than a SAFEARRAY of bytes) then you shouldn't try to *convert* it to narrow characters: Just `memcpy` its contents into a `BYTE` buffer and it should work.